# Tabbing the printed fields evenly using awk

Tags: shell, awk

i need help using awk. Thanks

i have a file it contains the following

```
text.txt  
The Hunger Games:Suzanne Collins:1:2:3
Weapon X:Stan Lee:3:4:5
```

the code that i was using to print the lines

```
awk -F '[:]' '{print $1, $2 ,"$"$3, $4 , $5 }' BookDB.txt
```

i wish for the out put to become like this

```
The Hunger Games     Suzanne Collins      1     2     3
Weapon X             Stan Lee             3     4     5
```

Comment: Why are you explicitly printing a `$` sign (`print .."$"..`) when your desired output doesn't contain a `$` sign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pipe awk output to `column` like this:

```
awk -F ':' -v OFS=':' '{print $1, $2 , $3, $4 , $5}' BookDB.txt | column -s ':' -t
The Hunger Games  Suzanne Collins  1  2  3
Weapon X          Stan Lee         3  4  5
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks :D btw what does OFS do?

Comment: `OFS` is used for setting a custom output field separator in `awk`.

Comment: Glad to know it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Comment: `awk` is doing nothing here and if specific fields were desired then `cut` would be the right choice of tool rather than `awk`.

Comment: @EdMorton: Intention of this answer to highlight use of `column` command for tabulating output of **any command**. `awk` was already in use in OP's question I just re-used it show use of `column`.

Comment: Yes it is effectively `column -s ':' -t file`  at present but I don't know intention of OP behind use of `awk`. I suspect may be OP is filtering/processing some data not shown in question.

Answer (score 1):

The output you show is not tab-separated, it's formatted as a table and for that all you need is:

```
$ column -t -s: file
The Hunger Games  Suzanne Collins  1  2  3
Weapon X          Stan Lee         3  4  5
```

If you really wanted it to be tab-separated then that'd be:

```
$ tr ':' '\t' < file
The Hunger Games        Suzanne Collins 1       2       3
Weapon X        Stan Lee        3       4       5
```

If you wanted specific fields:

```
$ cut -d':' -f 1,4 file | column -t -s:
The Hunger Games  2
Weapon X          4

$ cut -d':' -f 1,4 file | tr ':' '\t'
The Hunger Games        2
Weapon X        4

$ awk -F':' -v OFS='\t' '{print $1, $4}' file
The Hunger Games        2
Weapon X        4
```

If you don't have `column` but want tabular output, you can do it all in awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS = ":"; ARGV[ARGC] = ARGV[ARGC-1]; ARGC++ }
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
        if (NR==FNR)
            width[i] = (length($i) > width[i] ? length($i) : width[i])
        else
            printf "%-*s%s", width[i], $i, (i<NF?OFS:ORS)
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
The Hunger Games Suzanne Collins 1 2 3
Weapon X         Stan Lee        3 4 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get tab spacings as in your example:

```
awk -F: '{if(NR==2)$2="\t"$2;print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5}' OFS="\t" BookDB.txt
```

Setting `:` as field seperator and `\t` as output field seperator. Then for the second line `(NR==2)`, add `one extra tab` for the second field. Then print the fields.

Or even simpler (if it is acceptable for you):

```
sed "s/:/\t/g" BookDB.txt
```